# Strange PHP Mail() error

Tags: php, macos, email

I can't get my mail script to work. If i set $to to my me.com adress i doesn't send at at, but if i set $to to my gmail email adress it send, but the email comes up twice i mail osx......

mail.php

```
<?php
function send_req($namn, $datum, $tid, $telefon, $epost, $behandling, $id){
  $to  = 'xxx@me.com';
  $subject = 'Bokningsförfrågan';

  $message = '
  <html>
  <head>
    <title>Bokningsförfrågan</title>
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oxygen:300" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <style type="text/css">
    html{
    font-family: "Oxygen", sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    }
    table{
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    }
    a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000000;
    border-bottom: 1px solid blue;
    }
  </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    Du har fått en ny bokningförfrågan om ' . $behandling . ' <br>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>Namn</td><td>' . $namn . '</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Datum</td><td>' . $datum . '</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Klockan</td><td>' . $tid . '</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Telefon</td><td>' . $telefon . '</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Epostadress</td><td>' . $epost . '</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <a href="http://www.komitakt.se/boka/aprove.php?id=' . $id . '">Klicka här för att bekräfta</a>
  </body>
  </html>
  ';

  $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
  $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . "\r\n";
  $headers .= 'From: Komitakt Massage <xxx@gmail.com>' . "\r\n";

  @mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

}
?>
```

And i call the function only once like this:

```
include 'mail.php';
send_req($namn, $datum, $tid, $telefon, $epost, $behandling, $id);
```

Any ideas? :)

Comment: Please don't hide errors; check gmail, if there are twice messages, it's your script problem, else, is OS-x problem.

Comment: removed the @. If i open in gmail webmail it works, only receives once... What could be the matter with osx mail?

Comment: I dunno, i'm not a OS-x user, did you have tried asking in Apple communities ?

Comment: Oh, solved now... it seems "from:" needs to be a adress registerd at the host.